# How to display ads-script (Yandex Ads) into Gatsby MDX-posts

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm new user in Gatsby. I use MDX to create markdown posts. I want to display Yandex Ads script into my MDX-posts. It's Google Adsense alternative from Russia.

There is how Yandex Ads code is looking:

```
<div id="rtb-1"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (w, d, n, s, t) {
        function renderRtb () {
            Ya.Context.AdvManager.render({
                blockId: "R-A-12345-1",
                renderTo: "rtb-1",
                statId: 34567, // CROSS SECTION ID
                async: true
            });
        }
        w[n] = w[n] || [];
        w[n].push(renderRtb);
        t = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s = d.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src = "http://an.yandex.ru/system/context.js";
        s.async = true;
        t.parentNode.insertBefore(s, t);
    })(this, this.document, "yandexContextAsyncCallbacks");
</script>
```

Please, friends, tell me. How I can render this script into my MDX-posts? For example, I want to show Yandex Ads into center of my posts, or after some headings etc.

In html-file, like Jekyll, I just past my Ads-code where I want. But in Gatsby I get errors while building site. Im newbie in React.js, and if someone can help me, will be very good!

Sorry for bad English, friends. I'm from Russia. Love you all!

Comment: I found this solution in Russian forum: https://qna.habr.com/q/414689

But I can't understand, how I realise it in Gatsby (React.js). Please, someone can help me?

Comment: You want to include this script only inside blogposts or on every page of the website?